# Object persistence from WCFTestClient - Entity framework

Tags: c#, wcf, entity-framework, persistence, dbcontext

I am testing my WCF service via WCFTestClient. My methods run for me and return the correct values. However, when I execute from the WCFTestClient my entities are not persisting. Here is the method I am testing:

```
public PlayerActionResult DoAction(PlayerActionType type, int uid, string pparam = null, int amount = 0, string svalue = null) 
    {
        Player player;
        PlayerAction action = (PlayerAction)Activator.CreateInstance(null, string.Concat("Conquest.Players.Actions.", type.ToString())).Unwrap();
        action.Logic = (ActionLogic)Activator.CreateInstance(null, string.Concat("Conquest.Players.Actions.", type.ToString(), "Logic")).Unwrap();
        action.Logic.Action = action;
        // Verify executor exists
        if (!PlayerExists(uid))
        {
            return new PlayerActionResult(false, ResultType.NotFound);
        }
        else { player = GetPlayer(uid); }

        if (pparam != null & !PlayerExists(pparam))
        {
            if (!PlayerExists(pparam))
            {
                return new PlayerActionResult(false, ResultType.NotFound);
            }
            action.playerparam = GetPlayer(pparam);
        }
        PlayerActionResult result = player.DoAction(action);
        player.SaveChanges();
        return result;
    }
```

When I execute this same type of logic as a part of the "Player" class constructor(Player is derived from DbContext) the changes made DO save:

```
        public Player(int uid, string name)
    {
        this.Name = name;
        this.UserId = uid;
        this.Remorts = 0;
        this.Gender = Gender.Male;
        this.NumAttacks = 3;
        this.Movement = 30;
        this.PlayerClass = PlayerClass.Fighter;
        this.CurrentCont = Helper.GetRandom(3, 1);
        this.Kingdom = new HashSet<Kingdom>();
        this.Kingdom.Add(new Kingdom(this.CurrentCont));
        this.CurrentKingdom.Vault.AddItem(new Item(ItemType.LureVulture));
        this.CurrentKingdom.Vault.AddItem(new Item(ItemType.PotSpeed));
        PlayerAction action = (PlayerAction)Activator.CreateInstance(null, string.Concat("Conquest.Players.Actions.Pray")).Unwrap();
        action.Logic = (ActionLogic)Activator.CreateInstance(null, string.Concat("Conquest.Players.Actions.", "PrayLogic")).Unwrap();
        action.Logic.Action = action;
        this.DoAction(action);
}
```

Could anyone give me some insights as to why calling this logic within an DbContext derived object's constructor persists the data and calling the logic outside and then using SaveChanges() does not?

Comment: do you have all the datamembers and data contracts setup

Comment: Indeed, the only thing that I had to implicitly apply attributes to in my parameters was PlayerActionTypes which was throwing errors at me yesterday before I did. I don't recieve any errors like I was when my Contracts and Members weren't setup right, in fact no errors. Just no persistence.